# How make windows app always snap to one of the predefined layout frames

Tags: windows

Now that Windows 10 and 11 have introduced the concept of windows snap to a frame. I want to completely avoid floating windows and make sure that every window I open will be opened in one of the specific frames. Like a-frames that can be seen when hovering minimize button

I like the style of the mobile apps where all apps fill the entire space they have and do not partially cover each other

I know, a window can be repusiton by using <kbd>win+leftArrow</kbd> <kbd>win+rightArrow</kbd> <kbd>win+topArrow</kbd> <kbd>win+bottomArrow</kbd>
and moved between screen by using <kbd>win + shift + leftArrow</kbd> <kbd>win + shift + rightArrow</kbd>

Also, I discover the `snap` popup can be invoked by using <kbd>win + z</kbd>

[doc on that subject from window support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241)

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/fancyzones

Microsoft's own Powertoys has the Fancy Zones tool.

That tool has an improved version of the "open window in its last known position" function.

This, together with either the regular snap zones or Fancy Zone's own more capable zones will do what you want.

Comment: that is a dream that comes true.  Fancyzones does everything I want. thanks!